# Parse XML String to Sax parser android

Tags: android

I have a string containing an xml file data

such as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<data>

<type>
<lory>vroom</lory>
<car>crack</car>
</type>

<type>
<lory>doom</lory>
<car>chack</car>
</type>

</data>
```

this is kept in a String named label;

I use sax parser to retrieve the data as follows

```
SAXHelper sh = null;

            try {
                sh = new SAXHelper(newxml);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            sh.parseContent("");
```

Part of saxhelper class

```
class SAXHelper {


        public HashMap<String, String> userList = new HashMap<String, String>();
        private String data;

        public SAXHelper(String url1) throws MalformedURLException {
            this.data = new String(url1);
        }

        public RSSHandler parseContent(String parseContent) {
            RSSHandler df = new RSSHandler();
            try {

                SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
                xr.setContentHandler(df);
                xr.parse(data);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return df;
        }
    }
```

but i end with this error showing malformation error. for short i want to pass a xml string to a sax parser to set and get the result.

```
04-05 11:25:18.390: W/System.err(2646):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.openUrl(ExpatParser.java:760)
04-05 11:25:18.398: W/System.err(2646):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:289)
04-05 11:25:18.398: W/System.err(2646):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:322)
04-05 11:25:18.398: W/System.err(2646):     at .CompteDetails$SAXHelper.parseContent(CompteDetails.java:228)
04-05 11:25:18.398: W/System.err(2646):     at .CompteDetails$loadingTask.doInBackground(CompteDetails.java:202)
04-05 11:25:18.398: W/System.err(2646):     at .details.CompteDetails$loadingTask.doInBackground(CompteDetails.java:1)
04-05 11:25:18.398: W/System.err(2646):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
04-05 11:25:18.398: W/System.err(2646):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
04-05 11:25:18.398: W/System.err(2646):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
04-05 11:25:18.398: W/System.err(2646):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
04-05 11:25:18.398: W/System.err(2646):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
04-05 11:25:18.398: W/System.err(2646):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
04-05 11:25:18.402: W/System.err(2646): Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>..
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing raw XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-
```

hence the exception:

```
04-05 11:25:18.402: W/System.err(2646): Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```